# AWS SQS only returning 1 message at a time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm getting the SQS queue with the following. But it always returns only 1 message. Based on the params below, I'm expecting 10 messages. This is not a FIFO queue.

Is there a different config parameter to bring back more than 1 message at a time?

```
const receiveParms = {
      QueueUrl: queueURL,
      MaxNumberOfMessages: 10,
      VisibilityTimeout: 15,
      WaitTimeSeconds: 20,
      AttributeNames: ["All"],
    };

    const receiveCommand = new ReceiveMessageCommand(receiveParms);
    const msgData = await sqsClient.send(receiveCommand);
```

Comment: Is there more than 1 message in the Queue? The parameter says **Max**NumberOfMessages :-)

Comment: Yes. There is more than 1 messages. If I poll through the console, I can see more than one.

Comment: Just checking... how are you counting the number of messages received? Also, if you remove `WaitTimeSeconds`, does it sometimes receive zero messages? Please note that the [Amazon SQS Architecture](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-architecture.html) is highly distributed and therefore not all messages will necessarily be provided in response to a request.

Comment: You aren't guaranteed to receive more than one message, regardless of how many messages are in the (distributed) queue, to the best of my knowledge. Related discussion [here](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/324).

Comment: I run through a loop to count the # of messages

Comment: Thing is even with a loop you cannot guarantee you'll ever see all the messages in the queue because they are not guaranteed, thus in my view, making an SQS queue pretty unusable unless you delete messages as you read them. but even then, it seems there is no guarantee you ever see the remaining messages.

Comment: Could you check MessageGroupId property of your messages in your queue ? Messages that have the same MessageGroupId will be processed sequentially. That may be your issue

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to resolve this issue recently and have discovered a few details that help explain why SQS (non FIFO) behaves in this way.

[`MaxNumberOfMessages`](https://--max-number-of-messages)

The maximum number of messages to return. Amazon SQS never returns more messages than this value (however, fewer messages might be returned). Valid values: 1 to 10. Default: 1.

[`VisibilityTimeout`](https://The%20duration%20(in%20seconds)%20that%20the%20received%20messages%20are%20hidden%20from%20subsequent%20retrieve%20requests%20after%20being%20retrieved%20by%20a%20ReceiveMessage%20request.)

The duration (in seconds) that the received messages are hidden from subsequent retrieve requests after being retrieved by a `ReceiveMessage` request.

[`WaitTimeSeconds`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/receive-message.html#:%7E:text=a%20ReceiveMessage%20request.-,%2D%2Dwait%2Dtime%2Dseconds,-(integer))

The duration (in seconds) for which the call waits for a message to arrive in the queue before returning. If a message is available, the call returns sooner than `WaitTimeSeconds`. If no messages are available and the wait time expires, the call returns successfully with an empty list of messages.

---

So if you have a single consumer and you want to get a specific message, then a way to do this is by repeat `ReceiveMessage` requests that utilise a `VisibilityTimeout` long enough to ensure that you only get different messages in each request.

Note, if you delete each message as it is received, then that makes things easier because you will only receive messages that are not deleted in subsequent requests. This is of course not ideal if there are multiple consumers of the same queue for the same message.

Even with all that said, you are still left with no guarantee that you will receive the messages you want in 1 or more requests.

---

So after all that, I was left with a redesign, just removing SQS from the equation and using a lambda to send information that otherwise would have been an SQS message, but stored in proper storage instead for retrieval and processing later.

Not exactly a solution, but a few work arounds and an alternative that may help.